# Twitter Bootstrap typeahead doesn't except returned array

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a modified Twitter Bootstrap typeahead found here.

https://gist.github.com/2935906

I can't understand why the code below does not work. If I use the testArr it works fine, but as soon as I return the resultsArr I created from some Google Maps code it fails. A console.log(resultsArr) shows that all is fine with it though. Ideas?

```
var testArr=new Array("One","Two","Three");

$('#map-query').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query) {

        var resultsArr = new Array();

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': query }, function (results, status) {

              for(i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
                  if(results[i].formatted_address) {
                        resultsArr[i] = results[i].formatted_address;    
                  }
              }

              console.log(resultsArr);


              return resultsArr;

      });

    },
    items: 10
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The return wasn't working because the request wasn't done. Also the gist patch I used for this can be found here. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, so suggestions on improving it are welcome.

https://gist.github.com/1866577

```
$('#map-query').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query) {

        var resultsArr = new Array();

          geocoder.geocode({ 'address': query }, function (results, status) {

              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                for(i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    if(results[i].formatted_address) {
                        resultsArr[i] = results[i].formatted_address;    
                  }
              }
            typeahead.process(resultsArr);
            }

      });

    },
    items: 10
});
```